# When I'm deploying ios app to simulator, it is not showing me complete screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I'm deploying ios app to simulator, it is not showing me complete screen.
I've already configure proper launch images.
simulator size (3.5")

[image]

Comment: That's probably because your screen is *non-retina* while the device your simulating is. You can scale it to a smaller size (click window> scale> some percentage) to see the whole screen at once.

Comment: I'm not able to scale it to a smallar size.

Comment: I'm referring to the simulator, make sure that it has focus then from the top toolbar click window > Scale

Comment: If you look at the image you linked you'll notice that there are actually scroll bars on the simulator so it is displaying the complete screen, you just need to scroll (which if you find annoying, you can scale it down).

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm able to scale but still not showing full screen or scroll in it.

Comment: [image here](http://prntscr.com/86fzo1)

Comment: Do I need to put scrollView in it? To show scroll on 3.5" screens.

Comment: Either a scroll view or have your autolayout constraints adjust things so they fit on the screen. You can also have things display differently using size classes if your only targeting iOS8+.

Comment: how do I add scroll view to already created layout?

Comment: I resize the simulator but it is still not showing remaining section.
I add scroll view to screen but it is not scrolling. http://i.imgur.com/Rdq8uOI.png

Comment: Your scroll view and constraints are probably not set up properly, in particular the scroll view's content size needs to be set correctly, if you are having trouble with this there is a lot of information (here StackOverflow and elsewhere about setting up a ScrollView). That said this doesn't really have anything to do with the simulator (you should get the same results if you deploy to a iPhone 4 or 4S, and as such you would probably be better off asking a new question with the specific details.

Comment: Thanks Jack, After uncheck the autoLayout its working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I'll write up an answer so that you can mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that because your monitor is not a *retina* display and the device your simulating is it takes up more space on your monitor (notice the scroll bars).

You can scale the simulator so you can see everything at once without scrolling by clicking on `Window > Scale > The percentage you want`.

Aside from the scrolling issue, if the actual content doesn't display then you will need to either place it in a scroll view or set up your constraints to handle the different screen sizes.